# Difference of Means for Stopwatch Times (independent t-test ?)

Tags: t-test, differences

I want to conduct a t-test for the difference of means between two samples, but the data are times (i.e., taken from a stopwatch). Is Student's T appropriate here ? I question this because I am not convinced that time follows a normal distribution. (Binomial ?)

**Many thanks** for your assistance here ! I am a great fan of the community, and this is my first question posed.

Notes: 
i. No, I couldn't find this anywhere on here or elsewhere, but welcome links.
ii. No, these are not time-series data.

Answer (score 0):

The standard 2-sample t test is appropriate provided the times in each sample are independent and can be described by a normal distribution. If the data are skewed or there are outliers, you may be able to transform the data (square root, log, etc.) to fix this. Otherwise there are analogous non-parametric tests that might be applicable.

Comment: Great, thanks ! This is exactly what I was hoping to hear. Also good to know that transformations are appropriate in this instance. Thank you for the reply.